# How to check whether a string contains a certain number of consonants and vowels?

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, combinatorics

I am trying to check the answer of the following problem programmatically. A manual calculation by hand must be possible but it is not my question.

> Given a string `"aeeiuchklpr"` of length 11. The character "e" occurs twice. It is not a typo. How many 6-permutations of the given string are there? The constraints are given as follows
>
> - the first character must be "h"
> - the last character must be a vowel
> - the number of consonants must be exactly 4
> - the number of vowels must be exactly 2

## Attempt

I don't know how to check the last two requirement above. Here is my attempt

```
Select[Permutations[StringSplit["aeeiuchklpr", ""], {6}],
  First[#] == "h" &&
    (Last[#] == "a" || Last[#] == "e" || Last[#] == "i" || 
      Last[#] == "u") &] // Length
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
VowelQ[s_String] := MatchQ[s, "a" | "e" | "i" | "o" | "u"];   

Select[Permutations[StringSplit["aeeiuchklpr", ""], {6}], 
    First[#] == "h" && VowelQ[Last@#] && Count[VowelQ /@ #, True] == 2 &] // Length
```

> ```
> 3120
> ```

Comment: It works perfectly! The last test (counting the consonants) is apparently optional. My bad!

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood. Yes, since you only have vowels and consonants.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Slightly different implementation as a one-liner, using a restricted pattern:

```
Count[Permutations[
  Characters["aeeiuchklpr"], {6}], {"h", m__, 
   vowels = ("a" | "e" | "i" | "o" | "u")} /; Count[{m}, vowels] == 1]
```

yields

```
3120
```

Comment: Very good! Thank you!